# How do you properly modify packet data in Scapy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tcp, dhcp, scapy

I’ve been using Scapy a bit and have been messing around with making packets. A problem I have is trying to specify certain data/options in packets. For example, I want to make a DHCP packet with option 60 but I don’t know what is valid input data to use for this. I know the packet should have a `DHCP.options` list and I can add options like this into the list, but how do I know what type and what range of data I can actually use? I also know I can type `DHCPOptions` at the interpreter to see that it’s a ‘vendor class id’, but how would I actually properly add it to a packet?

Another example: for a TCP timestamp option, I discovered that I have to enter that as `(‘Timestamp’, (int,int))`, in other words a tuple of the string `Timestamp` and a tuple within that tuple of two integers, within some sort of range I don’t know.

So ultimately, my question is where/how do I find out how to add valid input data into packets in Scapy? Is there a list or documentation somewhere? I’ve searched around but couldn’t find it even in the source code and the documentation doesn’t seem helpful at all. Help is greatly appreciated!

Sample code:

```
p = Ether()/IP()/UDP()/BOOTP()/DHCP()

# ?:what goes in the list to correctly add any option?
p[DHCP].options = [(?,?)]

# Trying to add option 60 here, unsure how
p[DHCP].options.append( ('vendor_class_id', ?) )
```

I use option 60 merely as an example, but I want to know how to add any valid option.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Could you please include a snippet of your source code to help illustrate the problem you are having? This will help someone to answer your question with specific instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, this might not be the full answer, since i also found it hard to find such info, but...

for some options, you can check in [dhcp.py](http://fossies.org/dox/scapy-2.2.0/dhcp_8py_source.html) how they are defined in `DHCPOptions` dictionary - for example, you see that `renewal_time` by its definition is of int type and as default set to 21600 - `IntField("renewal_time", 21600)`.

for other info, i suggest to dig through RFCs. for example, [RFC 2132](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2132) describes **DHCP Options and BOOTP Vendor Extensions**. 
[RFC 1497](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1497) solely refers to **Vendor options**.

Comment: This may be as helpful as it can get, and there are no other answers.